# Can a Hero Event be used on another Hero player?

Tags: last-night-on-earth

Can a hero player use a Hero Event card to help out another hero player's character, or must they only use Hero Events on their own character?

Comment: This question came from another user who posted it as part if another Question. I broke it into two.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Hero Events may be used on any hero unless they state otherwise. The [rules specifically](http://www.flyingfrog.net/lastnightonearth/pdf/LNOE_Rulebook_web.pdf) point this out:

> Events (Gold bordered) are taken into the player’s hand and kept secret from the Zombies. They can be strategically **played on any Hero** to give them an edge or save them from a grizzly fate. (page 4)
>
> Note that Events are not associated with any one Hero, but instead are held by the player to be used whenever is appropriate (some cards are listed as Play Immediately. These cards often have an effect that is used for the Hero currently taking their turn). (page 11)

Comment: "Grizzly" fate? I've never noticed bears in LNoE.

Comment: @deworde, don't blame me, it is a direct quote. So, no bears in the game, with a chance at being humorous like [magic the gathering](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Discussion.aspx?multiverseid=34209)?